Jsonata Get path element for each occurrence
My json:
{
  "adminShifts": {
    "1": [
      {
        "adminShiftId": 2490609,
        "annotation": "",
        "dutyID": 64404,
        "dutyLastName": "Name",
        "shift": 5,
        "smsNotify": true
      },
      {
        "adminShiftId": 2490611,
        "annotation": "",
        "dutyID": 64404,
        "dutyLastName": "Name",
        "shift": 6,
        "smsNotify": true
      }
    ],
    "2": [
      {
        "adminShiftId": 2490613,
        "annotation": "",
        "dutyID": 64404,
        "dutyLastName": "Name2",
        "shift": 5,
        "smsNotify": true
      },
      {
        "adminShiftId": 2490621,
        "annotation": "",
        "dutyID": 64404,
        "dutyLastName": "Name2",
        "shift": 6,
        "smsNotify": true
      }
    ]
  }
}

I want to receive an array in response ["1", "1",  "1", "2", "2"], that is, a array of keys from adminShifts without uniqueization, this is necessary to connect the output in grafana with a request like "adminShifts.*.dutyLastName" where the number of response lines must be the same
I probably need to use https://docs.jsonata.org/path-operators#-positional-variable-binding, but I can't figure out how
I have prepared an example online https://stedi.link/OGdLvyU
